# File uploader isn't showing the picture

Tags: javascript, reactjs, file, photo

I have a problem. I'm creating a small file uploader, that uploads photo. If the user press the icon a file uploader is showing up and then he can select a photo. After selecting the photo isn't showing. Where is exactly the problem?

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const Profilpic = () => {
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);

  const fileSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    if (event.target.files[0].size > 71680) {
      alert('File is too big! Wie Samys Dick');
    } else {
      setPreview(event.target.files[0]);
    }
  };

  return (
    <div>
      {preview ? (
        <img src={preview} alt="Preview" width="150px" height="150px" />
      ) : (
        <div>
          <label htmlFor="myInput">
            <i className="fas fa-user-circle"></i>
          </label>
          <input
            id="myInput"
            style={{ display: 'none' }}
            type={'file'}
            onChange={fileSelectedHandler}
          />
        </div>
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Profilpic;
```

Comment: Have you debugged by setting a breakpoint in the handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will work for you. You just need to create the URL for your selected image.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [preview, setPreview] = useState(null);

  const fileSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    if (event.target.files[0].size > 71680) {
      alert("File is too big! Wie Samys Dick");
    } else {
      let img = URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
      setPreview(img);
    }
  };

  console.log(preview);

  return (
    <div>
      {preview ? (
        <img src={preview} alt="Preview" />
          ) : (
        <input id="myInput" type="file" onChange={fileSelectedHandler} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

At first remove the style tag from the input tag
then replace the function with that

```
const fileSelectedHandler = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);

    if (event.target.files[0].size > 71680) {
      alert("File is too big! Wie Samys Dick");
    } else {
      const reader = new FileReader();

      reader.readAsDataURL(event.target.files[0]);
      reader.onloadend = () => {
        setPreview(reader.result);
      };
    }
  };
```